# How to iterate over a nested array within an object within an array in Express-Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am rather new to Node.js, Express, Handlebars, etc. and I am attempting to build a dynamic dropdown menu using Node.JS and Express-Handlebars.

This is what my data looks like

```
var dropdownCategory = [
  {title:"Title", dropdownItem: [{title: "1"}, {title: "2"}]}, 
  {title: "Other title", dropdownItem: [{title: "3"}, {title: "4"}]}]
```

This is how I am iterating over it in express handlebars currently:

```
{{# each dropdownCategory}}
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
    {{title}}
     </a>
     {{# each dropdownItem}}
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a href="/{{title}}" class="dropdown-item">{{title}}</a>
     </div>
     {{else}}
     {{/each}}
  </li>
{{else}}
(...)
{{/each}}
```

I am always getting the first title from the `dropdownItem` only. Would appreciate your input on this. I assume it is a problem of nesting the second array within the object, but I honestly have no idea how to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First lets iterate over dropdownCategory and log it on to the console to see:

```
{{# each dropdownCategory}}
       {{log this}}
    {{/each}}
```

in console you should see this :

```
{title:"Title", dropdownItem: [{title: "1"}, {title: "2"}]}, 
  {title: "Other title", dropdownItem: [{title: "3"}, {title: "4"}]}
```

now we have to iterate over inside **"this"**.

```
{{# each dropdownCategory}}
       {{#each this.title}} //instead of "this.title", "this" or "." also correct
            {{this}}
          {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

you can always log it with "log" helper method.
I left the html part to you :) you can decorate the way u want.
I hope it helps